# Where can I find "The Jewish Problem" by Bruno Bauer since it is not available in Amazon, please?

Tags: history-of-philosophy

I am co-authoring a book and I bumped in a reference with a curious angle to it. I would like to check it. If you know who have a PDF of "The Jewish Problem" by Bruno Bauer I would appreciate your help. Greetings from Finland

Comment: Bookfinder  https://www.bookfinder.com/

Comment: https://hegel.net/bauer/BrunoBauer1843-Die_Judenfrage.pdf

Comment: Bruno Bauer didn’t write *The Jewish Problem.* He did write *The Jewish Question.*

Comment: @user58691 - The English translation is listed as "The Jewish Problem" on bookfinder and on the book filesharing site libgen.is (using the latter is technically not legal but the book is long out-of-print and the cheapest used copy on bookfinder goes for over 150 bucks)

Comment: Hmmm ... interesting title. 

Answer (score 1):

The best way is often to look for a [worldcat entry](https://www.worldcat.org/title/jewish-problem/oclc/2021951).

This shows you all the libraries in your area that have the book. Per interlibrary loan, you should easily be able to get it to a place close to you.