# I cannot find 20th-Century Philosophy: The Speculative Tradition, by Peter Koestenbaum. Where should I look for it?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, postmodernism, continental-philosophy

The paperback series *Readings in the History of Philosophy* is an 8 volume series about Western philosophy, from the Presocratics to the twentieth century. The Volumes and their Editors are:

- Greek Philosophy: Thales to Aristotle
  Reginald E. Allen, Indiana University
- Greek and Roman Philosophy After Aristotle
  Jason L. Saunders, University of California, San Diego
- Medieval Philosophy: St. Augustine to Ockham
  Father Allan B. Wolter, Catholic University of America
- The Philosophy of the Sixteenth and Seventeenth Centuries
  Richard H. Popkin, University of California, San Diego
- Eighteenth-Century Philosophy
  Lewis White Beck, The University of Rochester
- Nineteenth-Century Philosophy: Hegel to Nietzsche
  Alasdair Maclntyre, Oxford University
- Twentieth-Century Philosophy: The Speculative Tradition
  Peter Koestenbaum, San Jose State College
- Twentieth-Century Philosophy: The Analytic Tradition
  Morris Weitz, The Ohio State University

Now, only 7 out of 8 are available, either as ebooks or physical copies. It is very odd to find them all except Twentieth-Century Philosophy: The Speculative Tradition. I have been trying Amazon, Internet Archive, Peter Koestenbaum's website, university libraries, Simon & Schuster publisher, Jstore, etc. I would really appreciate it if someone can help me find it.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/90880/17209) help you?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking  Well, thank you for pointing this out. But the thing is, there are not a lot of libraries where I live. Also, there is not much interest in philosophy here. So, it is less likely that I will ever find it in any of the libraries in my area.

Comment: Well that's not the point. Your local library should be able to relay a request and organise a loan from whatever library has it. At least that's how I know it. People had books from a library in Göttingen loaned to Berlin, which is some hundreds of kilometres away. Youd need to find a library where it is for loan and just ask your local library or, if they are not cooperative, maybe even the one in question, and ask.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Alright.